# Oracl 11 g with Entity Framework C#

Tags: c#, oracle, entity-framework

When I try to use `.include` over 3 levels, I got this exception :

> Oracle 11.2.0.1.0 does not support APPLY

Code:

```
Include("AD_VEHICLE").
Include("AD_VEHICLE.AD_VEHICLE_AGE_RANGE_LKP").
Include("AD_VEHICLE.AD_VEHICLE_AGE_RANGE_LKP.AD_VEHICLE_AGE_RANGE_LKPNLS")
```

Note: I'm working with Oracle 12c and things were working fine, when I switched to Oracle 11g, this issue appeared.

Any suggestions?